# Get the distance of mouse movement

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mouseevent, mousemove

I have a form and inside it I got a small `Panel` called `Player`. How can I "link" the panel to user's mouse, so it will move as the mouse moves?

I've already subscribed `Player_MouseMove` to `Player.MouseMove` event but I can't figure out how much has the mouse actually moved. Only way I can come up with is to have a such:

```
private Point previousLocation;

private void Player_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int differenceX, differenceY;
    differenceX = e.X - previousLocation.X;
    differenceY = e.Y - previousLocation.Y;
    previousLocation = e.Location;
}
```

This seems pretty stupid, having an extra variable and calculating the difference everytime. Perfect way would be like `Player.LinkToCursor();` or such, but if there's no automated way, is there atleast a better way?

Comment: "...having an extra variable"   That's not an extra variable, that's a required variable.  You have to store it somewhere.

Comment: That's actually a pretty standard way of doing it. I've built a fair number of small 2D games, and the cycle of "get current, compare to previous, assign current to previous, repeat" is used all over the place - time intervals and button-press detection some other common ones.

Comment: @SteveWellens Yeah I was hoping it would already be stored in the `MouseEventArgs e` or so, which would make my variable useless :) But since it's not, you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx I can't see anything that would help you get this done any better.

There is however one thing you could do:

```
Point difference = e.Location - (Size)previousLocation;
```

Vector-arithmetics ;)

Comment: Was hoping to find something more useful, but I'll do it like this then :) Thanks for the answer!